# How can I show and image as on row when is selected?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

I'm very new in Xamarin.Forms and I'm trying to show and icon as selected indicator into selected item on TableView, but actually I'm a little lost...

My problem is, right now the icons are visible in each element of the list, I want set them as hidden by default and, when the user select any element of the list, show it (and of course, hide the icon of deselected row).

Any hint to accomplish it? Any idea or hint should be very helpful.

Here is the list code:

```
<base:ListView
                    ItemsSource="{Binding DeliveryMethodList}"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    RowHeight="60"
                    HeightRequest="120"
                    BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                    IsPullToRefreshEnabled="false"
                    SeparatorVisibility="None"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDeliveryMethod}">

                    <base:ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                             <StackLayout 
                                    Orientation="Horizontal"
                                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                                    <base:Image
                                        HeightRequest="{base:PointSize 15}"
                                        WidthRequest="{base:PointSize 15}"
                                        Source="{x:Static res:Images.AcceptIco}"
                                        IsVisible="{Binding IsSelectedDeliveryIconVisible}"
                                        VerticalOptions="Center"
                                        HorizontalOptions="Center"/>  

                                    <base:Label 
                                        FontSize="{StaticResource FontSizeMedium1}"
                                        Text="{Binding name}"
                                        HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                        VerticalOptions="Start"
                                        TextColor="White"/>
                             </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </base:ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </base:ListView>
```

and here is my ViewModel method to selection and the item source:

```
    bool _isSelectedDeliveryIconVisible;
    public bool IsSelectedDeliveryIconVisible
    {
        get { return _isSelectedDeliveryIconVisible; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _isSelectedDeliveryIconVisible, value); }
    }

    ObservableCollection<DeliveryMethod> _deliveryMethodList;
    public ObservableCollection<DeliveryMethod> DeliveryMethodList
    {
        get { return _deliveryMethodList; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _deliveryMethodList, value); }
    }

    DeliveryMethod _selectedDeliveryMethod;
    public DeliveryMethod SelectedDeliveryMethod
    {
        get { return _selectedDeliveryMethod; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _selectedDeliveryMethod, value);
            if (_selectedDeliveryMethod != null)
            {
                IsSelectedDeliveryIconVisible = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Best!

Comment: where is IsSelectedDeliveryIconVisible?  Is that a property on the VM, or on DeliveryMethod?  Remember that each cell in your list is bound to an instance of DeliveryMethod.

Comment: Hi @Jason, I updated the code. `IsSelectedDeliveryIconVisible` is a property on the VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make the IsSelectedDeliveryIconVisible an attribute of the DeliveryMethod class so it can have a different value for each item in the list.

When a user selects a delivery method, you'll need to set IsSelectedDeliveryIconVisible for each item in the list (see code below). That will ensure that at most one icon is visible at one time. Your existing binding should work with this new code.

```
public class DeliveryMethod 
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public bool IsSelectedDeliveryIconVisible {get; set;}
    // ...
}

DeliveryMethod _selectedDeliveryMethod;
public DeliveryMethod SelectedDeliveryMethod
{
    get { return _selectedDeliveryMethod; }
    set
    {
        SetProperty(ref _selectedDeliveryMethod, value);
        if (_selectedDeliveryMethod != null)
        {
            DeliveryMethodList.ForEach(d => { d.IsSelectedDeliveryIconVisible = (d.Id == value.Id); });
        }
    }
}
```